# Prove independence of limit point of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of random variables on a
>   probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, and let $\mathcal{G}$ be
>   a $\sigma$-subalgebra of $\mathcal{F}$. Assume $X_n$ is independent of
>   $\mathcal{G}$ for each $n$, and that $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n = X$
>   almost surely. Prove that $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$.

This result makes sense to me intuitively, but I'm not sure how to prove the result. For some reason, this problem is in the "Characteristic Functions" portion of my probability textbook, so maybe there's some clever way to solve this problem with characteristic functions (I would be satisfied to see any solution though)?

I'm not so sure where to start

Answer (score 0):

Not true unless $\mathcal G$ is complete under $P$ or $X_n \to X$ at **every** point.

If $\mathcal G$ is not complete there exists $A \in \mathcal G$ and  a set $B \in \mathcal F$ such that $P(A\Delta B)=0$ and $B \notin \mathcal G$. Take $X_n=I_A$ for all $n$ and $X=I_B$ to get a  counter-example.

If $X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)$ for  every $\omega$ then this result is immediate from the fact that pointwise limit of a sequence of  measurable functions on $(\Omega,\mathcal G)$ is measurable.

Comment: If $X_{n}(\omega) \rightarrow X(\omega)$ for every $\omega$, I am having trouble proving this result

Comment: @kabom Consider the set $\Omega$ with the sigma algebra $\mathcal G$. $(X_n)$ is a sequence of measurable functions in this space converging at every point to $X$. Hence $X$ is measurable on this space which means $X$ is $\mathcal G$ meaurable.